# 3 VERTICAL LIGHT SWITCHES WITH DIMMER TO ALL 3-WAY LIGHT

Tags: electrical

I would like to add a 3 light switch that are vertical to save room.  They are to 3 different locations. That being said, I would like all of them to have dimmer lighting.  I can't find a rocker vertical 3-way switch with dimmable capabilities or anything I can do to add this feature.  My electrician is coming next week and would love to have all the parts ready for installation.  Your help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Tell your electrician what you want then (s)he can bring the parts.

Comment: Unfortunately, shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: Is expanding the box not an option? 3 dimmers in one gang is quite a lot of electronics to squeeze into that space...(which is why you don't see it made -- 2 dimmers in one gang is the most I've seen)